# Why does CryptoPunks does not use the Wyvern contract on OpenSea?

Tags: events, nft, erc-721, decentralized-exchange, opensea

Almost all NFT transactions on OpenSea are handled using the [wyvern contract](https://etherscan.io/address/0x7be8076f4ea4a4ad08075c2508e481d6c946d12b) which creates an [OrdersMatched](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x9dbaac0a919f1affe6b7b99b9fd21d536d6a667a118e54ae8e8625d8e9e4ed0c#eventlog) event for the NFT sale. However, I noticed that on sales for [CryptoPunks](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xfc1a9b93ac23e8e95de42bc6be8aff6ae45d8630f4d5d4cc3fa8be7a7eb8e9c7#eventlog) there is no OrdersMatched event, but a PunkBought event, which is created by the CryptoPunks contract itself.

Why does CryptoPunks not use the wyvern contract, and are there more exceptions on OpenSea besides CryptoPunks that do not use the wyvern contract?

Answer (score 1):

Neither of them were popular enough at the time they were released. This is why they were not built to be compatible.

Also there were no standards available at the time, so nobody had a specific direction to build towards.

Of course ERC-721 fixed the standards part. And general awareness of the new techniques is fixing new projects to come.